# How do you return a string (or any pass by reference type) from a function in C using LeetCode

Tags: c, pass-by-reference

Usually when returning a string or something that is passed by reference in C, in order to not just be returning temporary memory that is being wiped when the function returns, I was taught to either malloc the memory so that it survives after the function or use pointers to change a value outside of the function. The issues I`m having are, I have read and experienced in other languages that LeetCode does not like static or global variables, so that one seems off the table. Then for allocating memory on the heap, I can`t free the memory after the function returns since we are only writing the one function not the main. I seem to get a runtime error no matter what I try. How to other people use C in LeetCode?

For reference, here is some code I wrote for returning the longest common prefix of an array of strings that works in my local IDE, but the functions do not work in LeetCode. (By the way I know my resize function is super inefficient, it was really just for practicing dynamically allocating memory.)

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char* resize (char* arr,int size, char c);
char* longestCommonPrefix(char** strs, int strsSize); //strsSize is the number of words, not the overall number of characters in the 2d array.
void print(char** strs, int strsSize);
void clear (char** arr,int strsSize);
int main()
{
    char* strings[3] = { "flower","flow","flight"};
    char* a[4] = {"bittersweetheartbreakbittersweetheartbreaka", "bittersweetheartbreakbittersweetheartbreak", "bittersweetheartbreakbittersweetheartbreak","bittersweetheartbreakbittersweetheartbreak"};
    //print(strings, totalLen);
    //calling the function
    //printf("Hello world!\n");
    print(strings,3);
    //strings[0] = resize(strings[0],6, 'c');
    //print(strings,3);
    char* subString = longestCommonPrefix(strings, 3);
    printf("\nThe longest common prefix is: %s\n", subString);
    clear(strings,3);

    print(a,4);
    //strings[0] = resize(strings[0],6, 'c');
    //print(strings,3);
    subString = longestCommonPrefix(a, 4);
    printf("\nThe longest common prefix is: %s\n", subString);
    clear(a,3);
    return 0;
}


char* longestCommonPrefix(char** strs, int strsSize) {
            char* pre = "";
            int idx = 0;
            char letter = '\0';
            int match = 1;
                //BASE CASES:
            //case:empty array
            if(strsSize == 0)    return "";
            //case: only one word
            if(strsSize == 1)   return strs[0];
            //get first word
            char* first = strs[0];
            //check if the first word is empty, if so, the null char will be the longest prefix.
            if(first[0] == '\0')   return "";

            while(match){
                    //get a letter from the first word
                    letter = strs[0][idx];
                    //check the rest of the words for that letter at that idx
            for(int i = 1; i < strsSize; i++){
                    if(strs[i][idx] != letter){
                        match = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }
            //at this point if we have a match, we add that letter to pre
            if(match == 1){
                pre = resize(pre,idx + 1, letter);
            }
            idx++;
            }
        return pre;
        }




 char* resize (char* arr,int size, char c){
     int i;
    char* arr2 = malloc(sizeof(char)* size + 2*sizeof(char)); //we need to resize both arrays!
    for(i = 0; arr[i] != '\0'; i++){
        arr2[i] = arr[i];
        //
        //printf("\n%c copied: \n", arr2[i]);
    }
    arr = malloc(sizeof(char)* size + 2*sizeof(char));
        arr2[i] = c;
        arr2[i+1] = '\0';
    strcpy(arr, arr2);
    free(arr2);
    //printf("s is the new string", arr2);
    return arr;

}



void print(char** strs, int strsSize){

    for(int i = 0; i < strsSize; i++){
         for(int j = 0; strs[i][j] != '\0'; j++){
                if(strs[i][j] != '\0')
                printf("%c",strs[i][j]);
    }
         printf("\n");
    }
    printf("");
}

void clear(char** arr,int strsSize){
    for(int i = 0; i < strsSize; i++){
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}
```

## Here is the error message the LeetCode was providing:
Runtime Error Message:

==29==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000497 at pc 0x56172dcde625 bp 0x7ffea702c650 sp 0x7ffea702c640
READ of size 1 at 0x602000000497 thread T0
#2 0x7f06044e40b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
0x602000000497 is located 0 bytes to the right of 7-byte region [0x602000000490,0x602000000497)
allocated by thread T0 here:
#0 0x7f0605129bc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
#4 0x7f06044e40b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
0x0c047fff8040: fa fa 00 00 fa fa 01 fa fa fa 01 fa fa fa 03 fa
0x0c047fff8050: fa fa 00 00 fa fa 01 fa fa fa 02 fa fa fa 03 fa
0x0c047fff8060: fa fa 00 00 fa fa 03 fa fa fa 02 fa fa fa 05 fa
0x0c047fff8070: fa fa 00 00 fa fa 04 fa fa fa 04 fa fa fa 05 fa
0x0c047fff8080: fa fa 00 01 fa fa 05 fa fa fa 07 fa fa fa 03 fa
=>0x0c047fff8090: fa fa[07]fa fa fa 07 fa fa fa 07 fa fa fa 07 fa
0x0c047fff80a0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c047fff80b0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c047fff80c0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c047fff80d0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
0x0c047fff80e0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
Addressable:           00
Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
Heap left redzone:       fa
Freed heap region:       fd
Stack left redzone:      f1
Stack mid redzone:       f2
Stack right redzone:     f3
Stack after return:      f5
Stack use after scope:   f8
Global redzone:          f9
Global init order:       f6
Poisoned by user:        f7
Container overflow:      fc
Array cookie:            ac
Intra object redzone:    bb
ASan internal:           fe
Left alloca redzone:     ca
Right alloca redzone:    cb
Shadow gap:              cc
==29==ABORTING
Last executed input:
["flower","flower","flower","flower"]

Comment: what is the problem with leetcode to be more precise?

Comment: When I run the code in onlinegdb.com, I get an error `*** Error in './a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400aa8 ***` There must be something wrong with your management of dynamic memory.

Comment: I suggest to run your code in a debugger and/or use a tool that can check for memory access errors, e.g. `valgrind` on Linux.

Comment: @vmp 
29-ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000497 at pc 0x56172dcde625 bp 0x7ffea702c650 sp 0x7ffea702c640
READ of size 1 at 0x602000000497 thread T0
    #2 0x7f06044e40b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
0x602000000497 is located 0 bytes to the right of 7-byte region [0x602000000490,0x602000000497)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f0605129bc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
    #4 0x7f06044e40b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:

Comment: @vmp I`m sorry the entire error msg was too long for a comment, but it continued by mapping out addresses with the label "shadow bytes around the buggy address".

Comment: @Bodo, I`m definitely getting more insight about the issue in valgrind though I am having trouble tracing the exact error. I will try debugging it further in gdb and report back when I find it. Thank you.

Comment: @CyanMagentaYellowBlack You should build a debug version of your program to get error messages with source line information instead of addresses. [edit] your question to add error messages instead of using comments.